# I want to AVERAGEIF a filtered range

Tags: database, google-sheets

I wasn't sure how to title my problem but here it is:
So I have a google sheets database with two sheets. One sheet collects the form responses that are in survey-form, for example:
[How my sheet collects responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X76kP.png)

Naturally, I can filter out the numbers using =VALUE(LEFT(CELL)) (see picture) in the same sheet, although this requires manual updating every time someone enters a response.

In the next sheet, I take the average of the values that contain the same username using the A B C D E columns as seen in the first picture. Like so:
[How the second sheet filters the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJaS0.png)

However, I want to do this all on the one sheet. I've tried several different ways but to no success. In other words, I want the second sheet to filter the number from the string automatically as I do not want to have to update it everytime.

So essentially, this image is what I want it to do everytime someone submits a new response:
[What I would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlLmO.png). However, this will not work as you cannot perform those operations on a range. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome. I think that you are over-complicating a reasonably straightforward task. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (exclude any private or confidential information) and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: What is the range of values for each of the five questions? Is the value always followed by a space then the "pipe" character? Is there any reason why the form response must include the value and text?

Comment: @Tedinoz Hi, so yes the | and description tells the instructor what the rating means.

Here is a copy of the form: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uo1cf2RwuPT-vGHffFMasxXUsqo8pf3V3bmfB1ObD-4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Since the is only one row of data in your spreadsheet, I'm having some difficulty understanding how the average is being calculated/used. Would you please add more data so that this aspect becomes more pronounced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are collecting course evaluations from participants by using a Google Form.

Each participant will lodge an evaluation of the course leader for 5 areas of performance. Each evaluation result is a combination of a score value and some appropriate text describing the course leader's performance in those areas.

You want to track the average of the evaluation scores over each area of performance, and in total, for each course leader.

---

There may be many solutions to this question and this answer should be considered as one solution.

This answer has three parts:

- The Google Form Response Sheet
- an `onFormSubmit` function: This function is an installable trigger and is executed every time there is a form response. The script extracts the score value from the respective evaluation strings using `split`, converts the score from a string to text, and adds the score and a total to additional columns on the Google Response Sheet.
- an analysis sheet using `query`. This calculates the average scores in each area and in total grouped by each course leader. As each new Form Responses are received, the analysis sheet is automatically update the average for existing course leaders, or begins tracking new course leaders.

---

This function should be installed as an `onForSubmit` trigger.

```
function buildscore(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var sheetname = range.getSheet().getSheetName();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // create a temporary array to store values and later set values for Columns H to M
  var temp = [];


  // A) Quality of Communication 
  var comms = e.namedValues['A) Quality of Communication'][0].split(" ")[0];
  comms=+comms;

  // B) Enforcement of Rules
  var rules = e.namedValues['B) Enforcement of Rules'][0].split(" ")[0];
  rules=+rules;

  // C) Maturity during event
  var maturity = e.namedValues['C) Maturity during event'][0].split(" ")[0];
  maturity=+maturity;

  // D) Event pace
  var pace = e.namedValues['D) Event pace'][0].split(" ")[0];
  pace=+pace;

  // E) Event quality
  var quality = e.namedValues['E) Event quality'][0].split(" ")[0];
  quality=+quality;

  var total = (comms+rules+maturity+pace+quality)*4;

  // push the scores and total onto the temporary array
  temp.push(comms);
  temp.push(rules);
  temp.push(maturity);
  temp.push(pace);
  temp.push(quality);
  temp.push(total);

  // update Columns H to M for the scores and total
  var targetrange = sheet.getRange(row,8,1,6);
  targetrange.setValues([temp]);

  return;
}
```

---

Enter this query in cell A2 of the Evaluation Analysis Sheet.

```
=query('Form Responses 4'!B3:M,
       "Select B, Avg(M), Avg(H), Avg(I), Avg(J), Avg(K), Avg(L) 
       where B is not null 
       group by B 
       LABEL B 'UserName', Avg(M) 'Mean Total Score', Avg(H) 'A) Communication',
       Avg(I) 'B) Rules', Avg(J) 'C) Maturity',Avg(K)'D) Pace', 
       Avg(L) 'E) Quality'"
       ,0)
```

---

**Form Response Sheet plus extra columns**

[image: Form Response Sheet]

---

**Evaluation Analysis Sheet**

[image: Evaluation Analysis Sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `QUERY` function on the "Evaluation Summary Statistics" sheet.

- Create a new sheet (to avoid the various formula already included on "Evaluation Summary Statistics"; you can add Conditional Formatting separately).
- In Cell A2, enter the formula:
  `=query('Training Evaluations'!A3:O,"Select C, O,J,K,L,M,N LABEL C 'UserName', O 'Mean Total Score', J 'A) Communication', K 'B) Rules', L 'C) Maturity', M 'D) Pace', N 'E) Quality'",0)`
- Add additional Form Responses, the username and values from the Form Response sheet are automatically displayed on the QUERY.

---

[image: Sample data]

Comment: I apologise for not explaining myself correctly, this is not what I was looking for sorry. I wanted to use the 'Training Evaluations' D-H columns. Because of the nature of google sheets, when a new submission is submitted, the formulas in the J-O columns will not be automatically applied and you are required to manually add the forms in the newly created row. Because this part cannot be avoided, I wanted to use the summary statistics sheet to find every submission with the same username and calculate the mean. Example: 5 submissions for 'Bob' in 'Training eval.' would result in 1 row forHisAvg

Comment: @LiamB I'm sorry, I didn't understand this in the first instance. I think the other answer addresses the issues.